# fread. fseek. ftell. " warning: value computed is not used "

Tags: c

how to instead of

```
char text[10000];
```

do

```
char text[fp_len];
```

i also get this warning:

> warning: value computed is not used

```
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen(path, "r");
int fp_len;
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END)+1;
fp_len = ftell(fp); 
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
printf("%d---", fp_len);

char text[10000];
fread(text, fp_len, 1, fp);

printf("%s", text);
```

should i also add:

```
text[]= '\0'
```

to the bottom. ( above printf )

Comment: This: `fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END)+1;` triggers the warning, since you never use the computed value (result of fseek plus one). You probably want to set the current file pointer to the end of the file, so just drop the +1.

Comment: `char text[fp_len];` is not possible you have to allocate it dynamically: `char * text = malloc(sizeof (char) * fp_len);`. But you have to free it after usage: `free(text);`.

Comment: @AndreKampling: it's possible in C! ever heard of VLAs ? BTW  `sizeof(char)` is 1. it's just problematic if the file is too big (stack overflow)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Sure `sizeof(char)` is 1 but I like it to write code with explicit statements also it is good for explanation. And yes VLAs are possible, but only when your compiler supports those **C99** extension. Visual Studio 2010 for example doesn't support it, where gcc v4.7 supports it. So in short in ANSI C or C89 it's not possible.

Comment: @AndreKampling VS is not the best compiler there is :) anyway you're right about using heap and not stack to read big files.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Yes ;-), I always fall over things such as functions that are not implemented or being implemented not compliant to the standard in VS in contrast to gcc. VS is really annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get warning of unused value because when you add +1 to returned value, you are doing nothing

```
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END)+1;
```

is evaluated to

```
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
```

But compiler warns you about, maybe you forgot to assign result somewhere.

---

To read data, reserve memory in HEAP region using dynamic allocation otherwise you may enter to stack overflow if your `fp_len` is too big.

```
char *text = malloc(sizeof(*text) * (fp_len + 1));
```

And don't forget to include `stdlib.h`

Answer (score 1):

as noted in comments `fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END)+1` is just adding the return code of `fseek` to 1 (why would you do that?), and the result (useless) is dropped.

Now, you could create a variable length array (perfectly legal in C) using `char text[fp_len];`, that would work, but generally auto variable space is not designed to be big, so you can have "stack overflow" if the file is too big: in that case `char *text = malloc(fp_len)` is preferred.

If you want to null-terminate it (which is useful only if you want to `printf` the contents of the file, and if the file contains text), don't forget to add 1 to your buffer so you can legally do `text[fp_len] = '\0';`

Aside: `fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);` could be just `rewind(fp);`